# Proof of the axiom of replacement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As far as I understood, the axiom of replacement can be stated as follows: $\forall a\in A \exists !b \in B \space f(a) = b \rightarrow \exists C \forall b [b \in C \leftrightarrow b \in B \land \exists a\in A \space f(a) = b]$.

I have two questions: 1) is the formula above correct? 2) is the axiom of replacement a tautology? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: Thank you, Mr Scott. But, regardless of being an axiom, does the conclusion $\exists C \forall b [b \in C \leftrightarrow b \in B \land \exists a\in A \space f(a) = b]$ follows from the premise $\forall a\in A \exists !b \in B \space f(a) = b$ ? I can't find a way to prove it, if that's the case.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It's not an instance of replacement since the premise already assumes the range is contained in a set.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: You’re right: I somehow overlooked the fact that $b$ was restricted to a set $B$ on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly not a *tautology*, no matter how you slice it. Tautologies are things that are true in every interpretation of the language, no matter what. (Generally speaking, we are even more restrictive and say tautologies are only instances of propositional tautologies, whose validity can just be inferred from truth tables.) A statement being provable just means it is true in every interpretation where the axioms hold, not in every interpretation whatsoever.

What you wrote down is not the axiom of replacement, and it can be proven without replacement. Just let $C=\{b\in B: \exists a\in A\; f(a)=b\}.$ This set exists as an instance of the axiom schema of separation.

Replacement is  $$ \forall a\in A\exists!b\;\varphi(a,b)\to \exists C \forall b (b\in C\leftrightarrow\exists a\in A\;\varphi(a,b))$$ (where we universally quantify over $A$ and any loose variables that might occur in $\varphi$.) Note I've switched from the notation $f(a)=b$ to $\varphi(a,b)$ to emphasize, per Brian Scott's comments, that the "functions" we are concerning ourselves with are formulas, not sets. Also, as he notes, this is an axiom schema: there is one axiom for every formula $\varphi$.

The main difference here is that we don't specify that the range of the function is contained in a set in the premise. This is what replacement does: it tells us that if we have a function whose domain is a set, then its range it also a set.

We can't prove (every instance of) replacement from the other (non-replacement) axioms of ZF. It actually adds a lot of strength. Of course the replacement axioms are axioms in ZF, so we can prove them there... for the boring reason that they are axioms.

Finally, I'll emphasize that this business with $f(a)=b$ being a formula (rather than short hand for $f$ being a set of ordered pairs and $(a,b)\in f$) is really important. If we regard $f$ as a set instead, then we can easily prove its range is a set, and there is no need for replacement in doing this. Replacement is really for the situation where the function might otherwise be a proper class.